# What settings are appropriate for video course membership services?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm developing a video course membership service.
What settings are appropriate for it?
https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/12426199699985-Overview-of-video-privacy-settings

Also, I want to retrieve all the videos from my channel.
Which API should I use?
Is it possible to get a thumbnail of each video?

Thank!